# Vuex store update not applying re-render in component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, state, vuex

I am using Vue.js with TypeScript.

Link to my repo: https://github.com/Am4nzi/ac-vue

I have a component called `Albums.vue` which is rendering an iFrame. I am attempting to update the source URL of the iFrame when a button is clicked *in another component* called `AlbumsLeft.vue`. This updates a property in my store state called `albumURL`.

**The issue I am having is that the computed property I am using to set the URL in Albums.vue is not updating the URL in the iFrame element when the value in the store changes.**

My understanding is that a computed property should automatically update when it detects a change, however I could be mistaken. If this is the wrong approach, could anyone recommend a better one?

I can confirm that the state in the store does change as expected when the button is clicked via inspecting Vuex in Vue devtools.

I am setting the iFrame source URL dynamically using v-bind:

```
<iframe
        :src="imageSrcURL"
...
```

I am getting the URL from the store and setting it to a variable called imageSrcUrl via a computed property:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Albums extends Vue {
  get getAlbumURL() {
    return this.$store.state.albumURL;
  }

  private imageSrcURL = this.getAlbumURL;
}
</script>
```

The event handler within AlbumsLeft.vue is called changeAlbum:

```
changeAlbum(name: string) {
    this.$store.dispatch(
      'updateAlbumURL',
      'https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=4251477660/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=ffffff/tracklist=false/transparent=true',
    );
  }
```

This is my store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentAlbumId: '',
    albumURL: 'https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=3937120203/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=ffffff/tracklist=false/transparent=true',
  },
  mutations: {
    setAlbumID(state, albumId) {
      state.currentAlbumId = albumId;
    },
    setAlbumUrl(state, albumURL) {
      state.albumURL = albumURL;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    updateAlbumID({ commit }, albumId) {
      commit('setAlbumID', albumId);
    },
    updateAlbumURL({ commit }, albumId) {
      commit('setAlbumUrl', albumId);
    },
  },
  modules: {
  },
});
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
get getAlbumURL() {
  return this.$store.state.albumURL;
}

private imageSrcURL = this.getAlbumURL;
```

`getAlbumURL` changes correctly, but you're not reassigning it to `imageSrcURL`, which remains unchanged, hence no update in the template.

Either use `getAlbumURL` in `:src` of `<iframe>` or, if you do need `imageSrcURL` for some functionality you haven't shown here, place a `watch` on `getAlbumURL` and update `imageSrcURL` each time the former changes.

*Side note:* `imageSrcURL` should not be `private` if you use it in `<template>`. `private` means it's only accessible to the class. The template is outside the class. Basically, your production `build` will fail because of this error.

If the only reason for having `imageSrcURL` is because you can't mutate `getAlbumURL`, you can actually, using a setter:

```
get getAlbumURL() {
  return this.$store.state.albumURL;
}
set getAlbumURL(val) {
  this.$store.dispatch('updateAlbumURL', val);
}
```

Now you can safely use `getAlbumURL` as `v-model` or whatever. And you might also understand why you should avoid naming properties `getStuff`. `stuff` will do.

Comment: Thank you @tao! Using `getAlbumURL` in `:src` did the trick and that should be sufficient.

Also, thanks for the side note. I'm new to TypeScript and fairly new to OOP in general, so you've prevented a future headache!